# compare String with Array[String] in scala dataframe?

Tags: arrays, scala, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

How to compare String with Array[String] in scala ?

For example, if "a" belongs to ["a", "b", "c"].

I have dataframe df

```
          col1   col2
          a      [a,b,c]
          d      [a,b,c]
```

Expected output

```
          col1   col2        status
          a      [a,b,c]     present  
          d      [a,b,c]     missing
```

I wrote following script in scala

```
val arrayContains = udf( (col1: String, col2: Array[String]) =>
  if(col2.contains(col1) ) "present" else "missing" )
```

I append new column with my dataframe by filled this new column "status" as follows

```
df.withColumn("status", arrayContains($"col1", $"col2" )).show()
```

but it prompts me following error.

> (run-main-0) org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function(anonfun$1: (string, array) => string)

How can I resolve that issue ?

Comment: Can you also include the stacktrace for the exception that caused the failure?  One thing I can see is that  this code will cause a `nullPointerException` if the array is null.

Comment: @puhlen, Yes you are right and do you have any idea how to handle these null values. Infact I have to print present if there is null value in col2.

Comment: Finally, I managed null values with that script.

def compareStrAgainstArray = udf((array: mutable.WrappedArray[String] , str: String) =>
      if (((array == null) || array.exists(str.matches(_)))) "present" else "missing")

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import scala.collection.mutable

+----+---------+
|col1|     col2|
+----+---------+
|   a|[a, b, c]|
|   d|[a, b, c]|
|   e|[a, b, c]|
|  aa|[a, b, c]|
|   c|[a, b, c]|
|   f|       []|
+----+---------+

def compareStrAgainstArray() = udf((str: String,lst: mutable.WrappedArray[String]) => 
                                 if (lst.exists(str.matches(_)))"present" else "missing")  

df.withColumn("status",compareStrAgainstArray()($"col1",$"col2")).show()

+----+---------+-------+
|col1|     col2| status|
+----+---------+-------+
|   a|[a, b, c]|present|
|   d|[a, b, c]|missing|
|   e|[a, b, c]|missing|
|  aa|[a, b, c]|missing|
|   c|[a, b, c]|present|
|   f|       []|missing|
+----+---------+-------+
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for script but it prompts same error.

[error] (run-main-0) org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function(anonfun$compareStrAgainstArray$1: (string, array<string>) => string)


[error] org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function(anonfun$compareStrAgainstArray$1: (string, array<string>) => string)
[error]  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.apply_3$(Unknown Source)

Comment: Copy and paste the code that you are executing with the data. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you again but I have f = null rather than [ ] and for null I have to print present. I tried to update by putting condition that 

 if ((lst.exists(str.matches(_))) || lst==null)"present" else "missing"
but gave same error

Comment: it works well for non null values in col2 but I have some null values in col2 and it prompts me same error. anyway Thank you very much and if you have some idea how to handle null values in array string comparison. I would be grateful.

Comment: Thank you finally it solved.

def compareStrAgainstArray = udf((array:mutable.WrappedArray[String] , str: String) =>
      if (((array == null) || array.exists(str.matches(_)))) "present" else "missing")